# Weird white space after a H2 tag

Tags: html, css, whitespace

I have some weird white space. It's just a H2 title with a `font-size`, `color`, `margin-bottom`. There is no width or something on the H2 element.

How can I remove it?

[image: Example of issue]

The parrent element has a max-width:

```
display: inline-block;
max-width: 50%;
```

If I remove the max-width the white space is removed, because he uses the whole screen.

Comment: try `padding:0px;` .

Comment: Can you show the context or whole markup? Does the parent element have any size constraints?

Comment: There is no padding on the element. But thanks!

Comment: Because that's not enough space for `faketekst!` string. It requires new line.

Comment: The space must be there as a result of your HTML markup and CSS styling. You've shared none so it's plain impossible to say. If you don't know where to start, try the "Inspect element" feature of your browser's developer tools.

Comment: Is your actual CSS missing the tag selector?

Comment: @HubertZub, see my edit.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, tag selector?

Comment: You know, `h2 {...}`?

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález, of course I know H2. But my CSS is not missing it.

Answer (score 1):

`h2` is a block element. All block elements are automatically `width: 100%`. You can apply `display: inline-block` if you want to get rid of the extra space, but that may change your layout.

Comment: @tilldown But what do you want to accomplish? Do you want to hyphenate `faketekst!`? Hide what overflows? Expand first line to fit full width?

Comment: I want to remove the white space on the the right side. It's no problem if there are multiple rules.

Comment: @tilldown If that's all, `text-align: right;` will possibly do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Use Display inline in css as shown below:

```css
h2{
display:inline;
}
```

```html
<h2>Test</h2>
<h2>Header</h2>
```